# Statistical Compression Algorithms of Indexed Images

Tags: image, compression, pixel, indexed

When we apply  statistical compression algorithms such HUFFMAN on indexed images we know that pixels in such images contain index numbers that point to the RGB value in the color lookup table what are we compressed  pixels or lookup table or both?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is. Can you split the question into multiple sentences?

Answer (score 0):

You can only compress a pixel p(x,y) when it is find in the same image multiple times and you can find a shorter value for that pixel. Hence when you doesn't break the pigeonhole principle in mathematics you can compress both the pixel and the lookup table.